# Save data to localStorage from api

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to save data on Local Storage to make app works offline.
I want to get data from api, json data and save them to local storage,
PostList and Post are my classes

```
Future <PostsList> fetchPostsList(language) async {
  final response =  
    await http.get('https://sas-survey.urbanway.net/api/questions/1/${language}');

  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    // storagepost.setItem('resultPost', response.body);
    return PostsList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  }else{
    // return storagepost.getItem('resultPost');
    throw Exception('Filed to load post');
  }
}
final LocalStorage storagee = new LocalStorage('result_app');
static PostsList resultsListEn = new PostsList();
    _addItemEn( String id,
                String question,
                String photo,
                List answers,
                String categoryid) {
        setState(() {
          final resulten = new Post(id: id, title: question, image: photo, answers: answers, category: categoryid);
          print(resulten.title.toString());
          resultsListEn.posts.add(resulten);
          _saveToStorageEn();
        });
      }  
      _saveToStorageEn() {
        widget.storagee.setItem('en', resultsListEn.toJsonEncodable());
      }
new FutureBuilder<PostsList>(
              future: fetchPostsList(en),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  List<Post> questionsEn =snapshot.data.posts;
                  questionsEn.forEach((question){
                    _addItemEn(question.id, question.title, question.image, question.answers, question.category);
                  });
                  return Center();
                }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              },
            ),
```

this is my code what im missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-) for basic data. Add a toJson and fromJson method to your models PostList and Post and serialize it using json.decode/encode and save it as a string. When reading it back convert it back and use it. Examples of how I did it below. Your code is not complete enough to make adjustments to.

```
get postValue {
  var jsonContent = sharedPreferencesInstance.getString('post-key');
  if(jsonContent != null) {
     return Post.fromJson(json.decode(jsonContent));
  }
  return null;
}


set postValue(Post post) => sharedPreferencesInstance.setString(
    'post-key', json.encode(post.toJson()));
```